# Question for dummies. Error parameter on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have a basic knowledge on sheets. I have typed this parameter to get result X and to therefore dry down horizontally, so i can get the data i wanted. I have created a raw sheets and then another empty so i can combine different sets of data. What wrong thing i am doing?

As you can see on the pictures, i somehow did the first one(hostname) but im stucked on the second one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czw2g.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMtRa.png)

Comment: Hi! The way it is now, it's hard to see why this is not working. Consider including the formula used that worked and the one not working. Also, a print of the whole window, potential helpers can view the tab. Sharing a copy of the file (no confidential data) may also help... I'm learning how to make questions here myself. The better it is, the faster folks will help.

Comment: Yes, please share a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it). There is not enough information in your post or in the screenshots to even know where to look, let alone how to solve the issue. If you do share a link, please direct the volunteer contributor community here to exactly where to look. It would also help if you typed into an open column the results you *expect* to see the formula produce.